# How to apply transformations/filters on Lift Record Field before writing/reading its value

Tags: activerecord, lift, before-save, lift-mapper

I'm using Lift Record persistence and I want to apply some transformations on a Field whenever I set or get its value. For instance, for StringField I want to set it to lower case automatically in Record object.

```
object someField extends StringField(this, 64) {
   ...
   // how do I apply transformations here?
   ...
}
```

In Lift Mapper there is a method `setFilter` which does exactly that, but I can't find its equivalent in Record. In Mapper it looks like this:

```
object someField extends MappedString(this, 64) {
   ...
   override def setFilter = trim _ :: toUpper _ :: super.setFilter
   ...
}
```

Couple options I'm considering are:

- override `set` method, but there are many of them, I'm afraid to incompletely override subset of required methods, so I can't envision consequences. :)
- using lifecycle callbacks - seems like overkill.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks ;)

Comment: It seems that StringField also has a `setFilter` method as well, at least according to the API: http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.record.field.StringField The signature is `setFilter: List[(ValueType) ⇒ ValueType]`. Would that not work?

Comment: @jcern you are absolutely right, I don't know how I missed it. I honestly checked for that method, maybe it was too late and my brain was giving up :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @jcern for pointing this out:

Record has method `def setFilter: List[(ValueType) ⇒ ValueType]` which is very similar to `def setFilter: List[(FieldType) ⇒ FieldType]`.

It is used the same way, i.e. filter will be applied when setting or querying values. Here is a quick example:

```
class Tag extends MongoRecord[Tag] with ObjectIdPk[Tag] {
  ...
  object name extends StringField(this, 32) {
    override def setFilter = trim _ :: toLower _ :: super.setFilter
  }
  ...
}

Tag.createRecord.name("UPPER")                
// lowercases tag name:
//res1: Tag = class Tag={name=upper, _id=521bb306e4b04eacd74dd217}
```